# Adding JSF Custom component from backing bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to know if it is possible to add custom composite component to the view from backing bean?

I have custom component in /resources/comp/component1.xhtml with basic `<cc:interface>` and `<cc:implementation>`. Then I have a bean that is creating a Primefaces dashboard (which works fine; http://www.wobblycogs.co.uk/index.php/computing/jee/49-dynamic-dashboard-with-primefaces). I would like now to add the component1 to the dashboard from the dashboard's backing bean. Is this possible or do I have to create dashboard panel and use 'rendered' attribute to hide the component in case I want?

Main idea of this is to create user specific dashboard so that users can add custom widgets and change order in the dashboard.

Thanks!

Comment: I would use `<f:ajax>` with `rendered` attributes set on components.

Comment: It look like that you're [re-asked the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828540/programmatically-create-and-add-composite-component-in-backing-bean) and got an answer. You might want to delete the current question. In the future, it's better to edit and improve an existing question instead of asking a new one on the same subject :)