# NullpointerException on createComponent - no FaceletFactory

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, jboss7.x, facelets, composite-component

I've been trying to programmatically insert composite components into an UIPanel. For this I tried to use BalusC's [includeCompositeComponent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828540/programmatically-create-and-add-composite-component-in-backing-bean/15884083#15884083).

Only I have a NullPointerException on the first application.createComponent. It points to :

```
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.getComponentMetadata(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:237) [jsf-impl-2.1.25.jar:2.1.25]
```

Apparently there's no FaceletFactory in my FacesContext. I've looked in Debug mode into facesContext.getAttributes() and seen none.

Did I miss something ?

I use :

- JBoss 7.1
- jsf-impl-2.1.25
- RichFaces-4.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was the phase in which I was trying to insert my components. It was on `postInvokeAction`.

By doing it in `postAddToView`, I don't have the problem.

Comment: Well, I don't have the NullPointerException anymore. But I _do_ have other problems. I will see if `postAddToView` corrects them. Thanks.